# ui-date Datepicker for AngularJS not working

Tags: angularjs

when i used the directive,the pop-up doesnot show up.
my imports are

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular-ui-date/src/date.js"></script>
```

html code is

```
<body ng-app="appStore1">
<label>Select Date:<input type="text" ui-date ng-model="aDate"></label>
<div>{{aDate}}</div>
</body>
```

and javascript code is

```
var app=angular.module('appStore1',['ui.date']);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  When you have a moment, please take a look at the [tour] and the [help].  It is unclear what is not working from your question.  Can you add details, including any error messages that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included required references and able to reach to links.

Also code posted is not very much clear.

Follow syntax as mentioned on the ui-date site and try to start with example quoted there.